# Trying to insert into a database as well as post items from a multi select drop-down menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I need to be able to save selected items from a multi select drop-down list into a MySQL DB and display all the selected items. When I hit submit only the last item is saved.

Code originally was for a single item to be selected from a drop-down menu. I have modified it for selecting multiple items (for ease of editing by other people). I have tried various solutions including if is_array, for loops and foreach loops without any luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

HTML code

```
<select name="topic_id[]" multiple="multiple" id="select">
    <?php
     $topic_set = find_all_topics();
    while($topic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($topic_set)) {
        foreach($topic_set as $topic) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $topic['id'] . "\"";
            if($page['topic_id'] == $topic['id']) {
                echo " selected";
            }
            echo ">" . $topic['menu_name'] . "</option>";
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result();
    ?>
</select>
```

PHP

```
function insert_page($page) {
        global $db;
        $errors = validate_page($page);
        if(!empty($errors)) {
            return $errors;
        }
        shift_page_positions(0, $page['position'], $page['topic_id']);
        $post_t_ids = array();
        foreach($_POST['topic_id'] as $post_t_id) {
            $post_t_ids[] = (int) $post_t_id;
        }
        $post_t_id_joined = join('), (', $post_t_ids);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pages ";
        $sql .= "(topic_id, content) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES (";
        $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $post_t_id_joined) . "',";
        $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $page['content']) . "'";
        $sql .= ")";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error($db);
            db_disconnect($db);
            exit;
        }
    }
    if(is_post_request()) {
        $page = [];
        $page['topic_id'] = $_POST['topic_id'] ?? '';
        $page['content'] = $_POST['content'] ?? '';
        $result = insert_page($page);
        if(!isset($_POST['topic_id'])) {
            $_POST['topic_id'] = [];
        }
        if($result === true) {
            $new_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        } else {
            $errors = $result;
        }
    }
```

The result should be selecting multiple items from the drop-down list and upon clicking submit all selected items should save to the DB and displayed to a different page. No error messages pop up but only the last item selected gets saved and displayed.

Comment: How do you send your data to the server? Post a code.

Comment: This is code for the form <form action="<?php echo url_for('/content/content_pages/new.php'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">. This is the pertinent PHP at the top of the page if(is_post_request()){$page = []; $page['topic_id'] = $_POST['topic_id'] ?? '';$result = insert_page($page);if(!isset($_POST['topic_id'])){$_POST['topic_id'] = [];} if($result === true){$new_id = mysqli_insert_id($db); $_SESSION['message'] = 'The page was created successfully.'; redirect_to(url_for('/content/content_pages/show.php?id=' . $new_id));}else{ $errors = $result;} Hope that helps.

Comment: Please, put it as code block at your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PHP “insert multiple” to insert all 4 rows at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513873/using-php-insert-multiple-to-insert-all-4-rows-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

Your part to make an `sql` statement is wrong. It will produce you something like:

`INSERT INTO pages (topic_id, content) VALUES ('1), (2), (3','content')`

You need to modify your code to get a proper sql statement. Of course, I would recommend you to use prepared statements:

```php
$params['content'] = $page['content'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO pages (topic_id, content) VALUES (:id, :content)');

foreach($_POST['topic_id'] as $id) {
    $params['id'] = $id;
    $stmt->execute($params);    
}
```

If you still want to use your approach, you should do it like this:

```php
$content = $page['content'];
$makeValues = function($id) use ($content) {
    return "($id, '$content')";
};
$post_t_id_joined = implode(', ', array_map($makeValues, $post_t_ids));
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages ";
$sql .= "(topic_id, content) ";
$sql .= "VALUES $post_t_id_joined";
```

Comment: I'll have to spend time researching prepared statements. I'm no too well versed in PHP so that is something i will need to learn. I did try both suggestions and each threw different errors. I'm sure some of my code was not in the right places. I'd like to be able to post all the code somewhere so someone could take a look at it and pinpoint where the problem lies with not being able to select multiple items. Thanks for the attempt to help, I'm going to step away from it and work on other things for a bit. .

Comment: @cfelker You can use any of php sandboxes to post your code. Also, you can update your question with actual code, so I will try to help you. Good luck :)

Comment: I put what should be the necessary code here git@github.com:clintdf/php_cms.git. Thanks for any help you can provide.